# How to change the list of signals catched with 'Piping core dumps to a program'?

Tags: c++, c, linux, coredump

How can I change the list of signals catched with 'Piping core dumps to a program'('man core')?

Currently catched the only SIGQUIT/SIGILL/SIGTRAP/SIGABRT/SIGBUS/SIGFPE/SIGSEGV/SIGXCPU/SIGXFSZ/SIGSYS signals.

I need to add some other signals like SIGPIPE. How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to core dump on SIGPIPE?

Comment: Because I want to see the call stack. Why not?

Comment: SIGPIPE is an 'informational' signal indicating that a process is trying to write to a pipe which has no readers. It should be cleanly handled by the writing process rather than causing an abort.

Comment: If it's your own code, you can install a signal handler for SIGPIPE and call abort() in the signal handler.

Comment: What's bad is that I want to see the call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement from the `signal(2)` manpage answers your question:

```
During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default; the
dispositions of ignored signals are feft unchanged.
```

If another words, you can only set signals to be ignored in an arbitrary process and only if the arbitrary process does not override that by configuring its own signal dispositions.

Any signals which are not ignored will revert back to default behaviour when a process is started (executed). The only way to change signal handling behaviour in that case is within the process itself.

You can use `sigaction(2)` to change signal handling behaviour in a process for which you have the source code. Otherwise, there is nothing you can do.